# Problems in manifest file

Tags: android, exception, android-manifest, syntax-error

Im using novoda project to use a jar gps locator (https://github.com/novoda/Novocation)
with so I keep on getting the same error on the manifest file -
"attribute is missing the android namespace prefix", Cant figure out why, ideas? thats a really big bummer since by the documentation and the sample app I can really use his gps locator...

Here Is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mappermate"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name="com.mappermate.application.MappermateApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <!-- Uploader Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.UploaderActivity" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Login Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.LoginActivity" />

    <!-- Register Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.RegisterActivity" />

    <!-- Authentication Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.AuthenticationActivity" />

    <!-- Exit Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.ExitActivity" />

    <!-- Main Menu Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.Delete_MainMenuActivity" />

    <!-- Preferences Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.PreferencesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme" >
    </activity>

    <!-- My Location Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.mappermate.ui.phone.MapperMateScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.novoda.location.receiver.ActiveLocationChanged" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.novoda.location.ACTIVE_LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.novoda.location.receiver.PassiveLocationChanged" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.novoda.location.receiver.RestorePassiveListenerOnRestoredConnectivity"
        enabled="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.novoda.location.receiver.StopPassiveLocationUpdatesOnLowBattery" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.novoda.location.receiver.RestorePassiveListenerBoot" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see wrong is

```
enabled="false"
```

needs to be

```
android:enabled="false"
```

In addition, you need to add

```
</manifest>
```

at the end of your manifest.

Comment: Dude you are my savior!
cant beileve I missed that android:enabled...

TNX ALOT!